# Show version of ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember does the following when starting an application:

```
if ( Ember.LOG_VERSION ) {
  Ember.LOG_VERSION = false; // we only need to see this once per Application#init
  Ember.debug('-------------------------------');
  Ember.debug('Ember.VERSION : ' + Ember.VERSION);
  Ember.debug('Handlebars.VERSION : ' + Ember.Handlebars.VERSION);
  Ember.debug('jQuery.VERSION : ' + Ember.$().jquery);
  Ember.debug('-------------------------------');
}
```

I would like to show the version of `ember-data` as well. How can I do this? I see no `VERSION` in `ember-data`.

Comment: i have updated my answer, finally it's possible to show the ember-data version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ember-data` is still considered *alpha* it has no version information. This might change as soon as the core team begins to publish RC releases. Also till revision **12** there was a need to define the revision of the API you where using in the store like:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  ...
});
```

But the need to define a revision is removed now in revision **13** as you can read [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-data-0-13.html).

The only thing what comes in mind you could do, is to read out the first line in the `ember-data` js file that looks like this:

```
// Last commit: 3981a7c (2013-05-28 05:00:14 -0700)
```

and extract at least the commit hash nor the date.

Hope it helps

**Update**

finally the version number was included and can be accessed with `DS.VERSION` example [here](http://jsbin.com/alawer/2/edit).